# left join two table using id mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and my database name is members

`loanapplications`

id is: `loan_id`
columns: `loantype, contact_number.. etc`

`users`

id is: `id`

how can i left join or other kinds of join the two so that i can display the loantype and contact number of users with same loan id and id?

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
select * from loanapplications l 
JOIN users u ON l.loan_id =u.id
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it seems like the simplest kind of LEFT JOIN to me. Is there any catch to it?

Comment: What column relates the two tables? What are you trying to accomplish? This question is missing all sorts of details.

Comment: i tried this query but it doesnt work: ("select * from loanapplications l JOIN users u ON l.loan_id =u.id", $db_handle); @Barmar

Comment: i already edited it @lucasnadalutti

Comment: Why would the loan ID be equal to the user ID? There should be a `user_id` column in the `loanapplications` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loanapplications` table should have a column that says which user applied for the loan, I'll call it `applicant_id`. Then the query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM loanapplications l
JOIN users u ON l.applicant_id = u.id
```